# How to set low priority for all child processes created by a PS script in the script

Tags: powershell, process, jobs

I want to set all child processes I start with a Invoke-expression to BelowNormal and I want to do it in the PowerShell script. I have

```
....
$scr= {
  param($di,$op, $log)
  [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.Priority ='BelowNormal'
  cd $di
  Invoke-Expression (".\Test.exe -x$op ") | Select-String -Pattern "" -Context 5 | Add-Content $log -Append
}
Sart-Job -ScriptBlock $scr -ArgumentList $d, $X , $fl
```

But when I look in the Task Manger I can see the Test.exe just have normal priority why?
How can I in my script ensure that all my child processes get belowNormal priority?

Comment: Try changing `[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.Priority ='BelowNormal'` to `(Get-Process -Id $PID).PriorityClass = 'BelowNormal'`

Comment: I believe task scheduler jobs are lower priority.  You can actually set the priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the thread's `.Priority` doesn't seem to have any effect in the process priority. Updating the `PriorityClass` of the job's process seem to solve the problem, testing with `cmd` I can see that is started with `BelowNormal` priority:

```
$job = Start-Job {
    (Get-Process -Id $PID).PriorityClass = 'BelowNormal'
    cmd /c ping -n 20 google.com
}
```